# how to change orientation of a webgrid in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I change the orientation of a webgrid in mvc?

Here's my web grid code for a horizontal grid. I want to show it vertically instead of horizontally because it contains only one row.

```
            <div id="DivGrid">
            @{
                var grid1 = new WebGrid(source: Model.Balance);
                @grid1.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "table",
                 headerStyle: "header",
                footerStyle: "grid-footer",
                 columns: grid1.Columns(
                 grid1.Column("Opening"),
                 grid1.Column("Earnings"),
                 grid1.Column("Closing")));
               }
        </div>
```